# Prove that if a is not 0, then |x|>c>0 implies |(1/a)-(1/x)|<(|a-x|/(c|a|))

Tags: inequality

For a,c, and x in the reals, prove that if a is not 0, then |x|>c>0 implies |(1/a)-(1/x)|<(|a-x|/(c|a|)).

I'm trying to practice these kinds of questions, and any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very straightforward. Did you even try anything?
$$\left|\frac1a-\frac1x\right|=\left|\frac{x-a}{ax}\right|=\frac{|a-x|}{|a||x|}<\frac{|a-x|}{c|a|}$$